# Use JQuery to get all table cells between two table cells on different rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm putting together a small calendar application and need to be able to pick a range of dates.

So I require the ability to select one TD in the table that contains a month, then another TD which may or may not be on the same TR as the first.

I've been trying to use nextUntil to perform this but its clearly becoming unstuck with regards to intervening TR's.

In the example below I want to add a class to all the TD tags between #range-start and #range-end:

```
<tr>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-07">7</time></td>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-08">8</time></td>
  <td id="range-start"><time datetime="2011-11-09">9</time></td>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-10">10</time></td>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-11">11</time></td>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-12">12</time></td>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-13">13</time></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-14">14</time></td>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-15">15</time></td>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-16">16</time></td>
  <td id="range-end"><time datetime="2011-11-17">17</time></td>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-18">18</time></td>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-19">19</time></td>
  <td><time datetime="2011-11-20">20</time></td>
</tr>
```

Anyone got any idea how to handle this?

Comment: You may want to either clean up your HTML or show more of it. It would be good to put these rows in a table with an id and a body tag. This would make some of the jQuery selectors more efficient and precise.

Comment: It's just a snippet for illustrative purposes :) I thought that was obvious!

Comment: If you would include the whole table structure with IDs, then peoples jQuery selectors would be more accurate to what you actually have. It's obvious what you are trying to do, but peoples answers could be more detailed and accurate with the whole table markup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

**Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Svzk3/)**

```
var start = false;
$("table td").filter(function(){
    if(this.id == "range-start" || start){
        if(this.id == "range-end"){
            start = false;
            return true;
        }
        start = true;
    }
  return start;

}).addClass("yourClass");
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing I can come up with is selecting all `td`s and then using `.index` and `.slice`: http://jsfiddle.net/AMBFZ/.

```
var first = $("td:eq(3)"), // first td
    last = $("td:eq(9)");  // last td

var allTds = $("td"); // all tds

var indexFirst = allTds.index(first), // index of first td in all tds
    indexLast = allTds.index(last);   // index of last td in all tds

// only tds between first and last (last should be included but .slice
// includes first and excludes last, so add one)
console.log( allTds.slice(indexFirst, indexLast + 1) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fromIndex = $("#calendar td").index($("#calendar #range-start"));
var toIndex = $("#calendar td").index($("#calendar #range-end"));

$("#calendar td").slice(fromIndex, toIndex).css("color", "Red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Some slight modifications to @pimvdb solution:

```
function PaintDates() {
    var cells = $("td"),
        startIndex = allTds.index($("#range-start")),
        endIndex = allTds.index($("#range-end"));

    allTds.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1).css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Native solution if you're interested:

```
var cells = document.getElementById('the_table').getElementsByTagName( 'td' ),
    i = 0, curr, result = [];

while( curr = cells[i], ++i ) {
    if( curr.id === 'range-end' ) {
        result.push( curr ); 
        i = -1;
    } else if( result.length || curr.id === 'range-start' ) result.push( curr );
}
```

Comment: Good to have for anyone who stumbles across this and requires it I guess. Thanks!